# send message API error

Tags: api, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api

I am sending send message request with XML bodyfrom my iphone application

```
<mailbox-item><recipients><recipient><person path='/people/93619553' /></recipient><recipient><person path='/people/116008244' /></recipient><recipient><person path='/people/96885725' /></recipient></recipients><subject>Message from butterfli</subject><body>Aasd</body></mailbox-item>
```

But getting this error

```
++ LinkedIn engine reports failure for connection 3CD3052A-7061-4EA0-8863-5584270B9177
The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 404.)
```

Code is

```
- (RDLinkedInConnectionID *)sendMessage:(NSDictionary *)shareDict {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[kAPIBaseURL stringByAppendingString:@"/v1/people/~/mailbox"]];
    NSString *xmlStr = @"<mailbox-item><recipients>";
    NSArray *toIdArray = [[shareDict objectForKey:@"privacy"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    for (int l=0; l<[toIdArray count]; l++) {
        xmlStr = [xmlStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<recipient><person path='/people/%@' /></recipient>",
                                                  [toIdArray objectAtIndex:l]]];
    }
    xmlStr = [xmlStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</recipients><subject>%@</subject><body>%@</body></mailbox-item>",
                                              @"Message from butterfli",[shareDict objectForKey:@"text_message"]]];

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<share><comment>%@</comment><content><submitted-url>%@</submitted-url></content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>",
                        [shareDict objectForKey:@"link_msg"],[shareDict objectForKey:@"link"]];
    NSData *body = [xmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"xmlStr..%@",xmlStr);
    return [self sendAPIRequestWithURL:url HTTPMethod:@"POST" body:body];
}
```

Amit Battan

Comment: Plz send me this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not a closed issue before it...

But now the solution is

its done...
Before it I am hardcoded the user id which is shown in the URL of user profile on Web.
But its working ok with id of user which is coming through API ..
But not getting why linkedin user different ids??

as
***LinkedIn use unique user IDs for each user/application combination to protect user's privacy. Only the application which originally requested (and got) authentication from the member can use that token to retrieve further information.***

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/3044